# SQL finding IDs that have multiple rows of criteria and creating a unique % formula

Tags: sql, teradata

So I have the following set of questions:

> The table 'visits' a list of all visits with three columns: Visit_ID,
>   Visitor_ID, Timestamp, and Page Name:
>   Visit_ID  Visitor_ID  Timestamp   Page_Name
>
> The table ‘first_visitors' a list of visitors and their first visit
>   with three columns: Visitor_ID, First_Visit_Date, and Channel
>
> A1.   Average number of visits, and visitors per pageover the last seven
>   days
>
> A2.   Visitor_id and Channel for visitors that have visited all three of
>   ‘home page’, ‘product page’, and ‘confirmation page’ at least once in
>   the last seven days
>
> A3.   Percent of SEM visitors that visit the ‘confirmation page’ within
>   thirty days of their first visit.

I have some concerns about translating a timestamp to a date and using date and date-7 to get a week. Is this the proper way to do this? (A1)

Also getting visitor_ids that have visited all 3 pages has been hard. I tried using the having clause but am not sure if this is correct. (A2)

Lastly getting a % out of dividing one aggregated column by another was difficult and I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about this? (A3)

My code is below. Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
--A1.   Average number of visits, and visitors per page over the last seven days
select
page_name,
count(visit_ID) as average_visits, 
count(DISTINCT visitor_ID) as average_visitors
from visits 
where cast(timestamp as date) between date and date-7 
group by page_name;

--A2.   Visitor_id and Channel for visitors that have visited all three of ‘home page’, ‘product page’, and ‘confirmation page’ at least once in the last seven days
select
a.visitor_id,
b.channel
from visits a
join first_visitors b on a.visitor_id = b.visitor_id
where cast(a.timestamp as date) between date and date-7 
and a.page_name in ('home page','product page','confirmation page') 
group by a.visitor_id
having count(distinct a.page_name) >= 3;

--A3.   Percent of SEM visitors that visit the ‘confirmation page’ within thirty days of their first visit.
select 
count(*) as visited_confirmation_page from
(select distinct a.visitor_id
    from first_visitors a
    join visits b on b.visitor_id = a.visitor_id
    where channel = 'SEM'
    and b.page_name in 'confirmation_page'
    and cast(b.timestamp as date) between cast(a.first_visit_timestamp as date) and cast(a.first_visit_timestamp as date)+30) 
count(*) as all_SEM_visits
(select distinct a.visitor_id
    from first_visitors a
    where channel = 'SEM')
((visited_confirmation_page / all_SEM_visits) * 100.00) as %_of_SEM_confirmations;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1 is ok, you just would do a minor syntax variation, instead of DATE better use Standard SQL's CURRENT_DATE:

```
where cast(timestamp as date) between CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE-7
```

The logic for A2 us correct, but you need to add the `b.channel` to the `group by` to avoid a syntax error. And you should try to join **after** aggregation:

```
select
a.visitor_id,
b.channel
from first_visitors b
join
 (
   select visitor_id
   from visits 
   where cast(timestamp as date) between date and date-7 
   and page_name in ('home page','product page','confirmation page') 
   group by visitor_id
   having count(distinct a.page_name) >= 3
 ) as a
on a.visitor_id = b.visitor_id
```

Your syntax for A3 will fail, but you're close:

```
select
 100.00 * -- multiply first, then divide
 (select count(distinct a.visitor_id) as visited_confirmation_page 
    from first_visitors a
    join visits b on b.visitor_id = a.visitor_id
    where channel = 'SEM'
    and b.page_name in 'confirmation_page'
    and cast(b.timestamp as date) between cast(a.first_visit_timestamp as date) 
    and cast(a.first_visit_timestamp as date)+30
 ) / 
 (select count(distinct a.visitor_id) as all_SEM_visits -- DISTINCT probably not needed
    from first_visitors a
    where channel = 'SEM'
 ) as "%_of_SEM_confirmations"
```